# Apache ORC file format: optional fields

Tags: protocol-buffers, orc

Reading the message specifications in the ORC file format (https://orc.apache.org/specification/ORCv1/) I see every field is marked optional.  Yet some of the fields are always required (such as the footerLength in the file Postscript).

So are all fields always present?  Or is there any way to tell which fields are truly optional and which are always required?